# Pagination SendinBlue Api Call

Tags: python, while-loop, sendinblue

I'm been trying to get data from the SendinBlue API. The problem is the API have a limit of 100 registers per call and my Python loop is not working properly. This is what I have so far, the call works fine.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize
import json

results = []
pagination = 0

url = "https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/smtp/statistics/events"

querystring = {"limit":"100","offset":pagination,"days":"15"}

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "api-key": "XXXXXXX"
}

#respuesta de la API
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring) 
#convertir json a diccionario
data = json.loads(response.text)
#convertir diccionario a DataFrame
base = pd.json_normalize(data,record_path='events')
```

The data structure is like this:

```
{'events': [
  {'email': 'chusperu@gmail.com',
   'date': '2020-10-18T17:18:58.000-05:00',
   'subject': 'Diego, ¡Gracias por registrarte! ',
   'messageId': '<202010181429.12179607081@smtp-relay.mailin.fr>',
   'event': 'opened',
   'tag': '',
   'from': 'ventas01@grupodymperu.com',
  {'email': 'cynthiaapurimac@gmail.com',
   'date': '2020-10-18T17:52:56.000-05:00',
   'subject': 'Alvarado, ¡Gracias por registrarte! ',
   'messageId': '<202010182252.53640747487@smtp-relay.mailin.fr>',
   'event': 'requests',
   'tag': '',
   'from': 'ventas01@grupodymperu.com'},
   ....
```

The loop I have tried is this, but it only paginated the first 200 registers. What I'm doing wrong?

```
for i in data['events']:
    results.append(i)
while response.status_code == 200:
    pagination += 100
    querystring ['offset'] = pagination
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    data = json.loads(response.text)

    for i in data['events']:
        results.append(i)
    else:
        break
print(results)
```

Comment: `for-else` loop would trigger `else` part after the loop so the loop stops.

Comment: Would you mind elaborate on the code? I can't make it work

Answer (score 0):

Finally get it.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize
import json

# Excel = "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Primero/DataSendin.xlsx"

pagination = 0

url = "https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/smtp/statistics/events"

querystring = {"limit":"100","offset":f"{pagination}","days":"3"}

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "api-key": "Your API key"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring) 

#respuesta de la API
try:   
    #convertir json a diccionario
    results = []
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    results.append(data)
    
    if not data:
        print("no hay data")
    
    else:
        while response.status_code == 200:
            pagination += 100
            querystring ['offset'] = pagination
            response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
            data = json.loads(response.text)
            results.append(data)            

            if not data:
                break          
            
except ValueError:
    "no data"

#convertir diccionario a DataFrame
final = list(filter(None, results))
base = pd.json_normalize(final,record_path='events')
base
```